# How would my JSON path look if I want to filter on description

Tags: c#, json, filtering, jsonpath

```json
[
  {
  
    "name": "NeWgR34",
    "path": "/NeWgR34",
    "attributes": {
      "description": [
        "De5cr$p(0#.,"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
   
    "name": "Newgroup",
    "path": "/Newgroup",
    "attributes": {
      "description": [
        "New group description"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I want to filter on description...
For filtering on something like name, it is something like this: `$..[?(@.name == 'Newgroup')]`...just curious what it would be for description which is an array inside of attributes -> description

I've tried something like `$..[?(@.attributes.description == 'Newgroup')]` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> `$..[?(@.name == 'Newgroup')]`

This would be more correct, but you likely don't need the `..`.  That's a recursive search, and it looks like your data is pretty well-defined and flat.  For this you'd just remove the `..`

```
$[?(@.name == 'Newgroup')]
```

> `@.attributes.description == 'Newgroup'`

There are a couple problems here.

1. You don't have any data that matches this as the `"NewGroup"` value is in the `@.name` property.  You'd need to compare the relative path (`@.attributes.description`) with a value that could appear there.
2. The value at `@.attributes.description` is an array, so comparing with a string isn't going to yield any results.

You'll need to use nested paths to make this work.

You want any item where `@.attributes.description` contains a value of `"New group description"`.

```
$[?@.attributes.description[?@=='New group description']]
```

Here's the breakdown:

```
$                                   // start at the root
 [?                                 // find elements where (*)
   @.attributes.description         // this value
    [?                              // has a value where (**)
      @=='New group description'    // the value is 'New group description'
    ]
 ]
```

* The upcoming IETF specification doesn't require parentheses around expressions.

** Because this inner path isn't compared with anything (no comparison operator), it becomes an existence expression.  Thus if *anything* matches, the node is returned.

You can see this working on my playground https://json-everything.net/json-path.

Comment: It's working for me! Just one more question...if I were do to regex for substring search...would I just change == to =~ in the following. So...
$[?@.attributes.description[?@=='New group description']] to
$[?@.attributes.description[?@=~/New group description/]]

Comment: Regex in the upcoming IETF spec (and thus in my lib) doesn't use the `=~` operator.  Instead there are two functions: `match()` and `search()`.  See my [docs](https://docs.json-everything.net/path/basics/#path-functions) for more info.